# Storing ASP.NET Core 5 production secrets on linux

Tags: asp.net-core

I am developing an ASP.NET Core 5 application which will be deployed to a linux server in production, and in this case Azure Vault is not currently an option. All of the other articles that I have found either use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection` (Windows only), or environment variables.

Due to the number of items I expect to store, the use of environment variables would be very cumbersome, and I expect to need to add or update the values without restarting the application.

Comment: Are you sure that Data Protection is not available in Linux? [This document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.dataprotection.repositories.filesystemxmlrepository.defaultkeystoragedirectory) e.g. refers to Linux and Data Protection.

Comment: What kind of data to you plan to store? "Due to the number of items I expect to store" doesn't sound like just the db server password. "add or update the values without restarting" you can apply changes w/o restarting the app.